# Create Windows XP restore partition

Tags: operating-systems, system-restore

I have a computer without CD Drive and use to install windows XP regularly as I am using for my cyber cafe. To make it easily install my window XP I would like to create a restore partition in my harddisk itself so that I can install or restore my windows XP operating system.

I found so many computer/laptop come with the restore OS by just press F11 or F12 while booting.

Is there anyway to manually create a restore partition for my Windows XP to restore my OS by just press F11 while booting.

Comment: Not suited here! Maybe somewhere else like SuperUser or one of the many forums that are dedicated to this stuff.

Comment: This Q is not related